# How to change image dynamically in drawable folder in Android studio?

Tags: android, directory, drawable, wallpaper, screen-lock

I have this snippet below:

```
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    try {
                        int random_int = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                        if(random_int == 0){
                            wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.phonewallpaper1, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
                        }else if(random_int == 1){
                            wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.phonewallpaper2, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
                        }else if(random_int == 2){
                            wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.phonewallpaper3, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
                        }else if(random_int == 3){
                            wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.phonewallpaper4, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
                        }

                        // set the wallpaper by calling the setResource function and
                        // passing the drawable file
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // here the errors can be logged instead of printStackTrace
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

This code is basically set randomly the screenlock wallpaper based on the static images (4 images) in drawable folder.
If I put 4 new images in a folder of android device, for example under "/storage/emulated/0/downloads/contents/".

How can you change the images dynamically in drawable folder based on images under "/storage/emulated/0/downloads/contents/"?

Is it easier just to replace programmatically the images in drawable folder, or just point the code to the folder "/storage/emulated/0/downloads/contents/" instead?

I have google around how to do this but cannot really find anything that set the screenlock wallpaper from a device folder.

Thank you

Comment: At run time your app cannot change files in drawable folder. That resource is read only. Only you can change the content with Android Studio.

Comment: So it just 1 possibility to point the wallpaperManager.setResource to a local folder?

Comment: A local folder is no resource. Search another member function.

Comment: tested like this below , get the black image instead of the wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

And `image1.canRead()` is not readable

```
File image1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/downloads/image1.jpg");
File image2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/downloads/image2.jpg");
if (image1.exists()) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EXIST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if (image1.canRead()) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "READABLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOT READABLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
int min = 0;
int max = 1;
//final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
FileInputStream fis;

Bitmap myBitmap1 =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image1.getAbsolutePath());
Bitmap myBitmap2 =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image2.getAbsolutePath());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (String)image1.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if (myBitmap1 == null) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
//  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (String)image1.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
// on below line initializing web view with id.
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
      int random_int = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
      if (random_int == 0) {
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(myBitmap1,null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
      } else if (random_int == 1) {
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(myBitmap2,null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

tested like this below , get the black image instead of the wallpaper.

```
        File image1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/downloads/image1.jpg");
    File image2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/downloads/image2.jpg");
    final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
    Bitmap myBitmap1 =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image1.getAbsolutePath());
    Bitmap myBitmap2 =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image2.getAbsolutePath());
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    // on below line initializing web view with id.
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                try {
                    int random_int = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                    if(random_int == 0){
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(myBitmap1,null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
                    }else if(random_int == 1){
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(myBitmap2,null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
                    }
```

Comment: `File image1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/storage/emulated/0/downloads/image1.jpg");` Have a look at `image1.getAbsolutePath()` and tell us the value.

Comment: Also try `image1.exists()` and `image1.canRead()` before use.

Comment: Also add `if(myBitmap1==null) Toast( my bitmap is null );`

Comment: the image1.exists() is exist, folder is correct, but myBitmap1==null is null

Comment: You canged the code and did not tell asked absolute path and did not tell what you changed. And did tell nothing about .canRead().

Comment: And i dont see you using exists() and canRead() in your code .

Comment: sorry i thought i just fixed it as i go, and don't want to add an answer again of my code, but if thats what you want...

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**